# Is it just the best thing to not choose the answer?

Tags: discussion, accepted-answer

I am having a feeling that if I choose an answer that may makr other people who have answered feel bad.

Also some answers are really close, it is hardly possible to choose without involving subjective feelings and other erronous human logic.

Afterall those asking questions here are not endowed with capacity of objective evaluation of precise logic 
In relation with the question asked so errors are to be expected.

The moderators @ChrisW and @Andrei should answer me as they are here with highest reputation.

Also @ruben2020, you answered [my question about the Sigdolvada sutra](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/q/28739/254) which was the more right answer but I choose santas answer because he bought the rihnocerous first.

So did you feel bad?

THIS IS A QUESTION RELEVANT TO **META** AS IT IS ABOUT HOW TO ACT ON THE STACK EXCHANGE WEBSITE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The official answers are here:

- [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)

  > Choose one answer that you believe is the best solution to your problem.
- [What does it mean when an answer is "accepted"?](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer)
- [How does accepting an answer work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/139866)

---

One of them says,

> **Please do not add a comment on your question or on an answer to say "Thank you".** Comments are meant for requesting clarification, leaving constructive criticism, or adding relevant but minor additional information – not for socializing. If you want to say "thank you," vote on or accept that person's answer, or simply pay it forward by providing a great answer to someone else's question.

... but comments saying "thank you" is tolerated on this site ... allowed as a politeness or a kindness (and not deleted by a moderator) ... especially if the comment says more than only "thank you" ... though it's true that voting and "paying forward" are also appreciated.

I noticed [you thanked ruben2020](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/questions/28739/how-to-navigate-the-impracticality-of-sigalovada-sutra#comment48490_28764) for example, I thought that was fine.

---

If you want to (beyond "accepting" an answer) reward an answer with extra "reputation" and attention, you can do that by awarding a "bounty" -- [What is a bounty? How can I start one?](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/help/bounty) -- but doing that isn't usual (isn't expected) on this site.

---

I think there are three benefits to accepting an answer:

- A hint to other users that your question was answered and your problem is (now already)  solved, and that you don't need any more *more* answers
- A hint to future readers with the same question, that this answer "worked for you" and may be an answer for them too, so read it carefully
- A statement that *at least one* answer was helpful or acceptable, complete -- so everyone can be happy. Conversely if you don't accept any answer that suggests that *none* of the answers solved your problem.